# Testing in Redmine

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, redmine, redmine-plugins

I've created a plugin for Redmine, and now am having difficulties writing the test cases for it. I am not using any framework like rspec for this, just the default asserts provided by rails.

I first ran my test by running the file trough the ruby interpreter.
This did not load the fixtures , so I found an alternative : I copied the fixtures file to ${redmine_root}/test/fixtures, from ${redmine_root}/vendor/plugins/my_plugin/test/fixtures, ran rake db:fixtures:load and now it loads them.

The controller that I'm testing has permissions set in init.rb, and requires authorization for some actions.

Although I open a session as a privileged user (Admin), I am not authorized to take the actions in the controller, somehow it does not load the permissions at the beginning of the test.

I have added the permissions manually in roles.yml, and ensured that the user has the appropriate role, but again nothing. 
The plugin works well, I am experiencing these problems only when testing. If I comment the line with before_filter :authorize in my controller, the test passes.

Am I missing something? Are the permissions from init.rb stored in a different place, or are loaded differently during the test phase?

Comment: What does the test look like? What does the authorize do? Pared-down code samples would be helpful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try using the rake tasks provided by Redmine to run your test suite. They should set everything up properly. You can search for them by using `rake -T search-pattern`. `rake -T test:plugins` will list the following ones:

```
rake test:plugins                        # Run tests for pluginsenvironment / Run the plugin tests in vendor/plugins/*/**/test (or specify with PLUGIN=name)
rake test:plugins:all                    # Run the plugin tests in vendor/plugins/**/test (or specify with PLUGIN=name)
rake test:plugins:functionals            # Run tests for functionalssetup_plugin_fixtures
rake test:plugins:integration            # Run tests for integrationsetup_plugin_fixtures
rake test:plugins:setup_plugin_fixtures  # Mirrors plugin fixtures into a single location to help plugin tests
rake test:plugins:units                  # Run tests for unitssetup_plugin_fixtures
```

Comment: Thanks! I didn't have knowledge of these commands. The fixtures are loaded properly now.